# What parts of Ubuntu are left in ChromeOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome-os

I read that ChromeOS was built on the Ubuntu kernel. So how much of the Ubuntu is left? Is X still available? What about a package manager?

Answer (score 4):

No part of ubuntu specifically are included in Chrome (Chromium) OS.  Chrome OS uses a modified, linux kernel.  It uses a custom display manager (so not X) and a minimal shell called cosh, without any advanced features found in bash.

It uses portage to manage packages (the gentoo package manager).